.NET Adding user to local Administrator group for domain-joined machine
I am having issues with adding/removing a domain user into the Administrator group o the local machine. I am piecing this with code samples from the web, but I am realising that I am not doing it right and am out of my depth with this one. Please help!
I have a function that gets the user from the domain (this part works well):
internal static async Task<DirectoryEntry> GetUserAsync(Logger log, string upn)
{
    try
    {
        await log.LogTraceAsync(string.Format("Retrieving user {0} from AD.", upn));

        DirectoryEntry user = null;

        using (var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain))
        {
            using (var searcher = new PrincipalSearcher(new UserPrincipal(context)))
            {
                UserPrincipal u = new UserPrincipal(context);
                u.UserPrincipalName = upn;
                searcher.QueryFilter = u;
                var result = searcher.FindOne();

                if (result != null)
                {
                    DirectoryEntry de = result.GetUnderlyingObject() as DirectoryEntry;
                    if (de != null) user = de;
                }
            }
        }
        return user;
    }
    catch (PrincipalServerDownException) { return null; }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        await log.LogErrorAsync("An error ocurred while getting user from AD.", ex);

        return null;
    }
}

Ths one works well. I can find the user that I am looking for.
Than I would want to add/remove this user in/from the local Administrator group of the local machine (which is also domain joined).
Here is the code for that (add only, remove is very similar).
internal static async Task<bool> AddUserInLocaAdministratorGroupAsync(Logger log, DirectoryEntry user)
{
    try
    {
        await log.LogTraceAsync(string.Format("Adding user {0} is in local machine {1} administartor group.", user.Name, Environment.MachineName));

        string uname = user.Properties["samaccountname"][0].ToString().ToLower();

        DirectoryEntry localMachine = new DirectoryEntry("WinNT://" + Environment.MachineName);
        DirectoryEntry admGroup = localMachine.Children.Find("administrators", "group");

        await log.LogTraceAsync(string.Format("Adding user {0}", user.Path.ToString()));

        admGroup.Invoke("Add", new object[] { user.Path.ToString() });

        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        await log.LogErrorAsync("An error acurred while adding user to local admin group.", ex);
        return false;
    }
}

The user.Path.ToString() is like this   LDAP://CN=Lastname\, Firstname,OU=NoPolicy,OU=_Users,DC=studio, DC=someorg,DC=net.
And this is the error that I get:  System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80005000): An invalid directory pathname was passed.
Clearly I am doing something wrong.
Can you help fixing this, or proposing a better way to make this call?
Thanks

Try rewriting the user object path from LDAP://<userPath> to WinNT://<domainFQDN>/<userPath> before calling admGroup.Invoke

Unfortunately, I get the same error An invalid directory pathname was passed.

I think you should remove the space character in LDAP Path,  it should be similar to this:     LDAP://CN=Smith,Jeff,CN=users,DC=fabrikam,DC=com

Unfortunately removing blank spaces did not fix this either.
